# how do I make a <div> span across the viewport horizontally when <body> is set to 90% margin 0 auto?

Tags: html, css

I've simply been unable to do this so far, and I've researched a lot of ways and I seem to be having no luck...

My HTML is

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
   <ul>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

and my CSS is

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

How do I get the .navbar to span horizontally across 100% of the viewport whilst keeping the elements within it within the 90% width of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use viewport units, in this case viewport width `vw`, where you give the `fullwidth` a negative margin to move it to the left edge

And use a `container` , don't set the `body` to a width less than the viewport

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90vw;

  /* just for demo purpose */
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -5vw;              /*  move it to the edge  */
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="fullwidth">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>LI
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>LI
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the body to 100%, then use a wrapping div at 90%. Don't set the body to 90%

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.wrapper { padding: 20px 0; width: 90%; margin:0 auto; background: #aaa; }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Nav Items</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  Content
  </div>
```